# How to Show thousands records to user and user have to select from that in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, dropdown

Currently I have thousands of records (It is still growing) in two tables and i want to display it in webpage so that user can select from it. Right now i am displaying it in Dropdowns so that user can select it.

Requirements:
- User can select Multiple records from dropdowns
- We have to implement Auto Complete also

We have tried Telerik Multi select dropdown, Kendo JS Drodpdown control and chosen select js. We are binding data through Ajax webservice. 
But it is taking much time to load dropdowns and user gets frustrated in waiting time.

Expected From all of you:
- If anyone can give us a better idea to implement above functionality then it would be awesome.
- Second thing is when dropdown are getting filled in between user can interact with other page component. Currently user has to wait for full page load.

Technologies: C# JavaScript Ajax

Comment: Have you checked where your bottlenect is? Is it the retrieval of these "thousands" of records from the server to the client, or the client rendering them?
As for the blocking issue, just load them asynchronously after the page has loaded

Comment: Retrieval From server is not taking much time. Binding it to front end is taking much time. And till the time user can not interact with other Page controls.

Comment: You may try data virtualization:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect/virtualization

Comment: @Werner: we have tried it but it is taking time to load data very first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/). This lets you load the autocomplete data dynamically after the user enters some charachters.
This should bring up the performance of your selection.

Check the [documentation page](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html) and the data property. There is a sample that shows you how to load your content via ajax. The dropdown will send a parameter to your server named `query`. With this parameter you can filter your data.
The plugin also allows multiple selection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are implementing it.